# alert duplicate records in csv upload

Tags: php, csv

my csv upload code is like this want to alert duplicate records which are already exists in database i am getting result with $status variable what should i do to alert every duplicate records what is way to alert every duplicate records

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
  $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
  { 

    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("$filename", "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $num = count($data);

            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {

                  if($c!="" && $c+1!="" && $c+2!=""){              
                    $a[] =  $data[$c];

                  }          
            }
        }
        $total = count($a);
        $m=0;
        $k = 1;
        for ($c=0; $c < $total; $c++) 
        {

           $address[$m][] = $a[$c] ;
           $z  = $address[$m][0];
           $q  = $address[$m][1];
           $q .= $address[$m][2];
           $q .= $address[$m][3];
           $q .= $address[$m][4];
           $q .= $address[$m][5];
           $q .= $address[$m][6];
           $q .= $address[$m][7];
           $q .= $address[$m][8];
           $q .= $address[$m][9];
           if($a[$c]=="")
           {
              if($k!=1)
              {

                $selectcon = "SELECT user_id FROM contact
                                WHERE user_id = '".$z."'";

                $selectRes = mysql_query($selectcon);
                if($rows = mysql_fetch_array($selectRes))
                {
                  $user_id = $rows['user_id'];

                  if($user_id == $z)
                  {
                    $staus = 1;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    $staus = 1;
                  }
                }

                  $insertParty = "INSERT INTO contact(user_id)values('$z')";
                  $res = mysql_query($insertParty);
                  $contact_id = mysql_insert_id();


                  $insertAddress = "INSERT INTO address(contact_id,address)VALUES($contact_id,'$q')";
                  $insertAddressRes = mysql_query($insertAddress);
                  if(!$insertAddressRes)
                  {
                    echo "<sctipt>";
                    echo "sweetAlert('oops','Import Data Fail','error')";
                    echo "</sctipt>";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     echo "<script>";
                     echo "swal('Sucess!', 'File Imported Sucessfully!','success')";
                     echo "</script>";
                  }
                  $m++;
                }
                $k++;

          }

        }
      fclose($handle);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a unique row inside database. You can't do it with PHP.

Add all columns to a single UNIQUE index, the you can't insert duplicate rows in that table.

Comment: but i want to to shows list of duplicate records to user but with this solution it 's not possible..

Comment: 1. You can use SELECT before INSERT, to check that if that row already exists or not. 2. By using UNIQUE row index, after executing insert command, check if it was successful or not, if not, check if that row already exists or not. If already exists, So that row already exists. NOTE: If most rows are duplicate, then use first approach, otherwise second one (Because of performance).

Comment: i am already using select before insert and i get result in that but problem is after that result it still run what should i do to stop that execution